# Laravel 4 migrations - class not found

Tags: migration, laravel

**This question is now solved - I used the below:**

And, problem solved thanks to IRC. I was told to run

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

This fixes the problem for me. It's likely related to my strange Composer setup.

---

I've just started playing with Laravel 4 for a possible future project, having come from Laravel 3. I have started off by creating a new migration, create_blogs_table using artisan:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_blogs_table --table=blogs --create
```

This generated the basic migration file structure which I then filled out a little more:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBlogsTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogs', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('blogs');
    }
}
```

I now try to run this migration using artisan once again:

```
php artisan migrate --env=local
```

*note I have a local database connection set up for domains with the .dev extension

Previously this would work just fine (in Laravel 3) but with Illuminate I then receive this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CreateBlogsTable' not found in /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php on line 301
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/gamingsite/artisan:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/gamingsite/artisan:57
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:106
PHP   4. Illuminate\Console\Command->run() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/console/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:95
PHP   6. Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:240
PHP   7. Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/console/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:107
PHP   8. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:69
PHP   9. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigrationList() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:75
PHP  10. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runUp() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:106
PHP  11. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->resolve() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:125
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/gamingsite/app/start/../storage/logs/log-2012-12-28.txt" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(77): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)
#2 /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(214): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#3 /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(278): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#4 [internal function]: Monolog\Logger->addError(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FatalErrorExcepti in /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 71
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/gamingsite/artisan:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/gamingsite/artisan:57
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:106
PHP   4. Illuminate\Console\Command->run() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/console/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:95
PHP   6. Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:240
PHP   7. Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/console/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:107
PHP   8. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:69
PHP   9. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigrationList() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:75
PHP  10. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runUp() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:106
PHP  11. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->resolve() /var/www/gamingsite/vendor/illuminate/database/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:125
```

I've checked and the database/migrations/ folder is certainly being autoloaded. I have no idea what the cause for this problem may be. Having asked on IRC and googled I'm still completely clueless so hopefully somebody can help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Laravel 4 (illuminate) migration class do not require you to set unsigned method. You can try this.

```
  class CreateBlogsTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogs', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('blogs');
    }
}
```

After having the chat with you, I knew two problems, one is that already mentioned above and the other problem is  due to the class not been registered into composer autoload. You will have to run manually : php composer.phar dump-autoload

Comment: Just tried that and still no luck. I still get the class not found error.

Comment: had same problem, running `php composer.phar dump-autoload` worked.

Answer (score 28):

I had this error on xubuntu and fixed it with sudo composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 15):

Artisan do the same work:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

Just a reminder for those who are not familiar with `composer`.

Comment: This is actually better than using composer, as it generates an optimized classmap

Comment: Actually this command didn't exist for me but `composer dump-autoload` solved the problem. Thanks! For the idea, at least.

Comment: Those who search the problem, please noticed that this question is 3 years ago and the version of laravel is 4. And the software itself is keeping changing. It means, **this command does't exist in latest artisan**. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Update your composer (`composer self-update`), then run your composer functions.