# Laravel 4 PHP Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel

I get the following error when I run phpunit with Laravel 4.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found in
```

composer.json

```
    "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

app.php

```
   'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase'
```

What ı should do?

Comment: You have not shown how you run PHPUnit. You have not shown how you've configured PHPUnit. See as well [Laravel 4 migrations - class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14069586/367456) which might not solve your issue but probably does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the autoload doesn't include the new requirement.

Be sure to run `composer update` to ensure that the file are downloaded and the autoloader is updated with that source.

If the files were downloaded and 'installed' manually run `php composer dump-autoload` to rebuild the autoload file.

Comment: I run  php artisan dump-autoload .

Comment: @Tim Did you mean, composer dump-autoload ?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem, so I thought I'd post my solution, even though it might be a different solution to what you were after.

I wanted to autoload my own libraries, so I added the following to my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Fhc": "app"
    }
},
```

What I didn't realise was that just above that line was the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
},
```

In essence, my modification had completely overridden the the code above. The solution was to merge the two together (as I should have done to begin with).

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Fhc": "app"
    }
},
```

Now it's all working as expected.

I hope this helps anyone else in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your "vendor" folder and the file named composer.lock after that run:

```
composer install
```

Pay attention to the output produced by composer.