# I install Laravel on window 7 and I got error message

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I install laravel when I run the demo file its gave me error message. error message is that:-

```
     Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\tests\TestCase.php on line 4
```

for solving this issues I tried to run phpunit app/tests/ command on command prompt but nothing happend. and my composer.json file is :--

```
  {
   "name": "laravel/laravel",
   "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
   "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
   "license": "MIT",
   "type": "project",
   "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
  },
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: Try composer update

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172011/laravel-4-php-fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-testing-testcase-not-fo

Comment: @AmitRay I tried this thing but error still same

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the tests folder in you laravel project root? and does it have TestCase.php inside of that?

Comment: yes I have Testcase.php file in root folder and when i run any files its gave same error message

Comment: What are the permission set to on the tests folder?

Comment: 755 permission and also changed 777

Comment: I am running D:\xammp\htdocs\lararvel and file is app\tests\TestCase.php