# laravel class not found (works on localhost but not on DO server)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, autoload

This is a repeat question - eg:
[Laravel 4 migrations - class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069586/laravel-4-migrations-class-not-found)

However, I've tried every solution (from every forum I could find) and cannot figure this out.

### Scenario

I created a Laravel 4 project on my local machine - added some classes, controllers, views, etc - the project works great.

I then copy this fresh repo onto my DO server - install dependencies with composer, etc. The project looks good, except for one page that shouts an error:

```
Class 'company' not found
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Database/­Eloquent/­Model.php593
```

You can view this page [here](http://tonylefler.com/hulp-laravel/public/explore/product/99).

### I've tried...

I've updated composer. I've tried "dump-autoload". I changed the 'minimum-stability' to 'stable' in the composer.json file (yes, this was a proposed solution on a forum post).

Other solutions have to do with adding "psr-4" or "psr-0" into the composer.json file depending on the composer version - tried both.

What boggles my mind about this the most, is that this page works great on my local machine, but not on the DO server....If you guys need more info about something to fish this answer out, just let me know.

Any help is appreciated :)

---

this is what my composer.json file looks like:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: i feel like it's a case sensitivity issue here. you can see under `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` if and how your class **company** gets loaded, since it works under your dev environment.

Comment: Can you add the code of page which is showing the error? If other things are working fine then I think there is no issue with composer.json.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Most probably (I'm pretty sure) your local environment is `Windows` and live server is `Linux`. So if the class `company` class file is used as `company.php` on local server then it's same `Company.php` on local server but as `Linux` follows case sensitive rules so it reads the `company.php` and `Company.php` as two different files.

So, if you have file name used `Company.php` then make sure you are refering the class using same case as `Company` not `company` (lower), in windows `c` and `C` doesn't matter but on `Linux/Unix` it does because of it's case sensitive nature.

Comment: indeed! I'm not sure why only one class didn't work (they all were set up the same way...), but changing the class names to lowercase and auto-dumping it again fixed it up. Thanks again

Comment: Perfect!!! In may case, my localhost is Mac, and even different it works. In my server I am using Apache with NGINX, then if it is different (uppercase and lowercase) it doesn't work. I have been wasted a lot time with that, but you were right. Thks.

Comment: Also, I had an issue with a class that had the file extension capitalized. I had `UserService.PHP` and renamed it to `UserService.php` fixed the issue, which took me a lot to find since all the capitalization was correct

Answer (score 7):

I have faced the same problem when I added/created a new model class called `Follower_Group` in a project I worked on, and after some search I came to a [solution](http://laravel.io/forum/08-21-2014-which-files-to-upload-to-server-after-composer-dump-autoload-locally) that worked pretty well in my case. Try this:

1. Execute the command `composer dump-autoload` in your local machine's terminal.
2. Re-upload these 2 folders `/bootstrap` and `/vendor/composer` from your local machine to your server.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using git, and you want Git to be case sensitive, adjust its configs:

Just use the following command for the current repository:

`git config core.ignorecase false`

For global setting:

`git config --global core.ignorecase false`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It was a path called app/helpers and inside it, my class Log:

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class Log {
 ...
}
```

On my local machine, it was working fine, but on the Server, I've got an exception.

The solution? Change the path name from "helpers" to "Helpers".

So, pay attention to the uppercase ;)

Answer (score -1):

During the upload sometimes it happens like the files get uploaded but the content inside it is blank.

I faced similar issue and fixed it re-uploading the file.

When I see the file on the server, it is of 0 bytes so i have to re upload the local file to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Run command `composer dump-autoload` in your local machine terminal, and then Re-upload composer folder from vendor in local machine to your server.

Answer (score -2):

THIS WORKS FOR ME ->
on your live server execute: `composer install` 
This should install all the necessary packages that are missing.

Hope this help someone!

Comment: What makes you think that any package is missing?

Comment: I dont know what exactly cause this but as far as I remember this solution somehow worked for me. :)