# Can't rollback laravel migrate

Tags: php, laravel, migration, rollback

I've created a migration for CreateUserTable successfully.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique;
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('user');
    }

}
```

but I'm not able to rollback:

```
$ php artisan migrate:rollback
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'CreateUserTable' not found","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php","line":301}}
```

Someone suggested to run below but it give me an other error:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Any solution to rollback and avoid this second error related to composer.json? I'[m using Laravel 4 with fresh installation.

Comment: Did you create the table using migration? Or by hand?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069586/laravel-4-migrations-class-not-found?rq=1) look similar?

Comment: @MarKBaker, Yes I created the table using migration.

Comment: where are you even running that composer command from ?

Comment: @lagbox, I'm running these commands under c:/xampp/htdocs/laravel and by using cygwin or cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

Rollback often requires you to run `composer dumpautoload` first. I've had the same problems in Laravel 5.1.

In your case `dumpautoload` should be in one word - this way it works for me.

And of course `composer`  should be run in a folder that contains the `composer.json` file. This would be your Laravel project folder.